# How to set countext_info with linked server connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, context-info, set-context-info

I am connecting to a server with linked server (I call this server customerServer) , I must set context info before exec a sp in CustomerServer...but I can't set context info by linkserver....what shoud I do?

this is the Context_infi and the SP:

```
DECLARE @L varbinary(128) SELECT @L = CONVERT(varbinary(128), '20020154,2;@^0')
 SET CONTEXT_INFO @L 
Exec SaleCustomerDebt 
@Filter =' and Main.PlaceId in (2)',
@UserFilter = NULL,
@CustomerId = ' + @cid +',
```

Note: without the "Context_info", SP Result would be incomplete

Comment: I have worked many times with linked servers and I have never used that. To me is japanese.

Comment: What exactly is it that you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: Can you not just run `EXEC LinkedServer.DB.sys.sp_executesql` with the above code (parameterized of course).

Comment: @Charlieface when you used sp_executesql this will change the session resulting in change of the scope. So, in case if you are setting some context_info it will set but won't be of any use unless you pass all your subsequent queries with same approach

Comment: @JamshaidK. Well you could do the whole batch in dynamic SQL, including setting the context and doing whatever it is.